# Translations not working in ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, translation

I know this has been posted multiple times but I've gone through each answer and found nothing worked for me...

**In module.config file**

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'abstract_factories' => array(
        'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterAbstractServiceFactory',
    ),
    'factories' => array(
        'translator'                    => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
        // various app services, but only listing first one
        'Application\Service\Fetch'     => 'Application\Factory\Service\FetchServiceFactory',
    ),
),
'translator' => array(
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
),
```

In *module/Application/language/* folder, I have these .mo and .po files:

- de.mo
- de.po
- en.mo
- en.po
- es.mo
- es.po
- it.mo
- it.po

**In one of the template view files:**

```
<div id="l_activite" class="homeTitle">
    <?php echo $this->translate('ActivitÃ©s', __NAMESPACE__);?>
</div>
```

**In Module.php**

I've cut this down to show how the *setProjectName* is invoked (which handles language translations and other things...)

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $application          = $e->getApplication();
    $eventManager         = $application->getEventManager();

    $moduleRouteListener  = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, array($this, 'setProjectName'));
}
```

I've cut the function down a bit to only show the lines concerning the language...

```
public function setProjectName(MvcEvent $e)
{
    // Session (lang & background)
    $session        = new Session();
    $request        = $e->getRequest();

    $lang = null;

    if (!$request instanceof \Zend\Console\Request) {
        $rm             = $request->getQuery();
        $lang           = $rm->get('lang');
    }

    $session->lang        = $lang        ?: $session->lang ?: 'fr';
    $lang                 = $session->lang;

    $session->langLocale  = strtolower($session->lang) . '_' . strtoupper($session->lang) . '.UTF-8';
    if ($lang == 'en') {
        $session->langLocale  = strtolower($session->lang) . '_' . strtoupper('US') . '.UTF-8';
    }

    $loc = setlocale(LC_ALL, $session->langLocale);
    // for Windows
    if (!$loc) {
        switch ($session->lang) {
            case 'en':
                $session->langLocale = 'eng';
            break;
            case 'de':
                $session->langLocale = 'deu';
            break;
            case 'fr':
                $session->langLocale = 'fra';
            break;
            case 'it':
                $session->langLocale = 'ita';
            break;
            case 'es':
                $session->langLocale = 'esn';
            break;
        }
        setlocale(LC_ALL, $session->langLocale);
    }

    \Locale::setDefault($session->langLocale);

    $translator          = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
    $langLocale          = $translator->getLocale();


    $e->setParam('lang', $langLocale);
}
```

I'm guessing the things I do in Module.php needs fixing in some way? I have that block of Windows code since we plan to run the app locally on some "offline" machines, but also running the app on the server (which runs linux).

We use `$lang` as `fr/de/en/it/es` because the database (sqlite) file is stored as *_fr.sqlite*, *_de.sqlite*, etc.

Comment: If I understand it's occur only on other machine. You have errors ? It's idiot but, intl is installed on the server machine ?

Comment: It doesn't work in dev (my machine) nor on production server but it used to work a while ago (before I changed Module.php), intl is installed in both environments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rename the **.mo** & **.po** files to be the same as 'eng', 'deu', 'fra', 'ita', 'esp'.

Comment: That works! for my Windows environment but not my dev and production servers, ideally I don't want to copy them to de_DE or whatever... will continue looking into this, maybe I can set the same local for both Windows and Linux ?

Comment: I think the name of the translation file that gets loaded is whatever value is set in \Locale::setDefault($session->langLocale);
...
Check file name and variable value for case sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of ZF2. The translatorinterface changed in 2.3

Comment: Latest, 2.3... Hmm we did move from 2.2 a few months back which might explain why it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

**In module.config file** You are using this translator

```
   'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
```

I think the problem is that you are some how importing or using an old translator namespace (path) file.

You need to look for a file where you are importing  the zend translator, like listener,  that can be in Listener/ApplicationListener.php

You will probably see  some thing like this.

you need to activate  the first one and comment the second one

```
use Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator; //use this namespace, it fits your configs.
```

// use Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator;

Hope that may give some guidance.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean?

Comment: I wanted that you take  a look at where  you import your zend Translator and that where write the use Zend \...... , i mean check the path of the namespace you are using. that is what i meant